# EMR Cluster: Exactly one of MasterInstanceFleet and MasterInstanceGroup must be specified

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, aws-cdk

I'm trying to create EMR cluster through cdk but getting error even after specifying master_instance_fleet & master_instance_group
Could not figuring out what is the problem, can some body please help

Below is my code:

`on_demand = _emr.CfnCluster.OnDemandProvisioningSpecificationProperty(allocation_strategy="On-demand")

```
    master_instance_fleet = _emr.CfnCluster.InstanceFleetConfigProperty(
        instance_type_configs=[_emr.CfnCluster.InstanceTypeConfigProperty(
            instance_type="m5.xlarge",
            weighted_capacity=1,
            ebs_configuration=_emr.CfnCluster.EbsConfigurationProperty(
                ebs_block_device_configs=[
                    _emr.CfnCluster.EbsBlockDeviceConfigProperty(
                        volume_specification=_emr.CfnCluster.VolumeSpecificationProperty(
                            size_in_gb=64,
                            volume_type="EBS Storage"))]
            )
        )],
        launch_specifications=_emr.CfnCluster.InstanceFleetProvisioningSpecificationsProperty(
            on_demand_specification=on_demand),
        name="MASTER",
        target_on_demand_capacity=64,
    )

    master_instance_group = _emr.CfnCluster.InstanceGroupConfigProperty(
        instance_count=1,
        instance_type="m5.xlarge",
        name="core",
        ebs_configuration=_emr.CfnCluster.EbsConfigurationProperty(
            ebs_block_device_configs=[_emr.CfnCluster.EbsBlockDeviceConfigProperty(
                volume_specification=_emr.CfnCluster.VolumeSpecificationProperty(size_in_gb=64,
                                                                                 volume_type="EBS Storage"))]
        )
    )

    instances = _emr.CfnCluster.JobFlowInstancesConfigProperty(
        master_instance_fleet=master_instance_fleet,
        master_instance_group=master_instance_group,
        additional_master_security_groups=default_security_groups,
        additional_slave_security_groups=default_security_groups,
        core_instance_fleet=master_instance_fleet,
        core_instance_group=master_instance_group,
        ec2_subnet_id=default_vpc_subnets[1],
        ec2_subnet_ids=default_vpc_subnets,
        ec2_key_name="mykey",
        hadoop_version="3.2.1",
    )

    
    application_properties = _emr.CfnCluster.ApplicationProperty(
        name="Hadoop",
        version="3.2.1",
    )

    _emr.CfnCluster(self,
                    id="myEMRCluster",
                    name="myEMRCluster",
                    instances=instances,
                    job_flow_role="EMR_DefaultRole",
                    service_role="EMR_EC2_DefaultRole",
                    auto_scaling_role="EMR_AutoScaling_DefaultRole",
                    visible_to_all_users=True,
                    ebs_root_volume_size=50,
                    applications=[application_properties]
                    )
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight modifications required to the above code, as per the aws docs we should specify either master instance fleet or master instance group like below

```
instances = _emr.CfnCluster.JobFlowInstancesConfigProperty(
                    master_instance_group=master_instance_group,
        additional_master_security_groups=[emr_security_group.security_group_id],
        additional_slave_security_groups=[emr_security_group.security_group_id],
         core_instance_group=master_instance_group,
        ec2_subnet_ids=default_vpc_subnets,
        ec2_key_name=self.node.try_get_context(stage)["ec2_key_name"],
        hadoop_version=self.node.try_get_context(stage)["hadoop_version"]
    )
```

This will create the cluster with ondemand instances